# Heroku Push Notifications Node Server Crashing

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, apple-push-notifications, pem

When I run a node server (node or nodemon) locally, I don't have a problem sending push notifications (via apn). But when I push to heroku, It can access the `key.pem` file. I have a `pushNotification` object in the `package.jason` file:

```
"pushNotification": {
    "production": false,
    "passphrase": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    "cert": "cert.pem",
    "key": "key.pem"
 },
```

This is the error my Heroku app throws when I try to send a push (minus the time stamp and other nonsense):

```
/app/node_modules/apn/node_modules/q/q.js:128
                         ^
                   throw e;
Error: ENOENT, open 'key.pem'
Process exited with status 8
State changed from up to crashed
```

And, I checked my branches and the file is on the server in the root directory. I'm having a hard time figuring out whats wrong or whats going on.

This is the first time I'm using Heroku, so I'm still learning.

Thanks!